# Spring boot 2.1 - NoSuchMethodError - getDispatcherServlet()

Tags: spring-boot

Just upgraded from **Spring Boot 2.0.6** to **Spring Boot 2.1.0** and am getting this error in my existing `@WebMvcTest` annotated tests:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.getDispatcherServlet()

My test looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = SubscriptionsResource.class, secure = false)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class SubscriptionsResourceTest {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @MockBean
  private SomeService someservice;

  @Test
  public void someTestMethod() throws Exception {
    //test content
    }
}
```

I had tried removing the `secure = false` in favor of @WithMockUser as suggested in release [notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes) but have the same issue.

TIA.

Comment: A `NoSuchMethodError` is almost always due to having an incompatible combination of versions on the classpath. What’s the full stack trace of the error? That’ll make it possible to identify what code is trying to call the method that doesn’t exist. Seeing your pom.xml or build.gradle would also be useful.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Thanks for the reply. I checked the pom again and removed `spring-test` artifact, version `5.0.7.RELEASE`. This resolved it. Congratulations on the new release, looking forward to using it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to me having `spring-test` dependency in my pom:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
   <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Removing this resolved the issue.